# jquery tablesorter uislider

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, uislider

I would like to have some slider bars embedded in a table, preferably each in a different cell, going down a column.

I'm constructing the table with:
`$('#namehere').tablesorter({table info here})`

and then calling the table with:
`<div id="namehere"></div>`

I'm not wanting these sliders to work as a filter, but rather an input variable to calculate other parts of each row. I've found a lot of posts with slider bars being used for filters, but this would not be the purpose of these slider bars.

I don't need the column with the slider bars sortable, but the other columns should be still.

Any thoughts on how to implement this? Any feedback would be appreciated.

So, the way things stand right now I have the following:

```
$(function() {
    DataArray = [];
    tempor = [];
    DataArray.push(['test_01','test_02','test_03','test_04','test_05']);
    tempor.push('1');
    tempor.push('2');
    tempor.push('   <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="OutputValue.value = parseInt(a.value)">'
                +'  <input name="a" type="range"  min="0" max="5" value="0"/>'
                +'  <br>'
                +'  <output name="OutputValue">0</output>'
                +'  </form>');
    tempor.push('4');
    tempor.push('5');
    DataArray.push(tempor);
    DataArray.push([1,2,3,4,5]);
    DataArray.push(['test_01','test_02','test_03','test_04','test_05']);

    $('#namehere').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgetOptions : {
            build_type   : 'array',
            build_source : DataArray,
            build_headers : {
                rows    : 1,    // Number of header rows from the csv
                classes : [],   // Header classes to apply to cells
                text    : [],   // Header cell text
                widths  : []    // set header cell widths
            },
            build_footers : {
                rows    : 1,    // Number of header rows from the csv
                classes : [],   // Footer classes to apply to cells
                text    : []    // Footer cell text
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And then for the HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="widget-build-table.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.blue.css">

    <script src="SliderBar_03_2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="namehere"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

The code will allow for a slider bar and display the value for it's position, but now the question is how to use that to compute other cell values...

Comment: Have you tried initializing the slider bar code before tablesorter?

The above method may not work since tablesorter removes, sorts then replaces all table rows, and could disrupt any code attached to the slider bars, unless you are using an HTML5 slider.

Could you share an example of what you are describing.

Comment: The suggestion of using the HTML5 slider was helpful. I was able to add the slider bar into the table with that, but need a way to reference and pull the positional value from the slider bar.

Let me see if I can post the code somewhere...

Comment: Just updated the question rather than posting the code somewhere. Also, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When binding to elements within a table that are dynamically modified, use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

So, you can modify your code as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2323/)):

```
$(function () {
    DataArray = [];
    tempor = [];
    DataArray.push(['test_01', 'test_02', 'test_03', 'test_04', 'test_05']);
    tempor.push('1');
    tempor.push('2');
    tempor.push('  <input name="a" type="range"  min="0" max="5" value="0"/>'
               +'  <br>'
               +'  <output name="OutputValue">0</output>');
    tempor.push('4');
    tempor.push('5');

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        DataArray.push(tempor);
        DataArray.push([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    }
    DataArray.push(['test_01', 'test_02', 'test_03', 'test_04', 'test_05']);

    $('#namehere').tablesorter({debug: true,
        theme: 'blue',
        widgetOptions: {
            build_type: 'array',
            build_source: DataArray,
            build_headers: {
                rows: 1, // Number of header rows from the csv
                classes: [], // Header classes to apply to cells
                text: [], // Header cell text
                widths: [] // set header cell widths
            },
            build_footers: {
                rows: 1, // Number of header rows from the csv
                classes: [], // Footer classes to apply to cells
                text: [] // Footer cell text
            }
        },
        initialized: function (table) {
            $('#namehere').on('change', 'input', function () {
                var $input = $(this),
                    // don't allow resort, it makes it difficult to use the slider
                    resort = false;
                $input.parent().find('output').html($input.val());
                $(table).trigger('updateCell', [ $input.closest('td'), resort ]);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code does allow me to get the slider bars, and update the value output by those slider bars in the table. I'm not quite sure I see though how to take the variable changed by the slider bar to use to compute another cell.
For example, let's say that I want the cell next to the slider bar to be (rather than the static 4) a function of the slider bar's location. let's say 4*output of the slider bar.
Do you know how to do that as well?